# Why does this activity crash when i try to upload to firebase databse?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app to track the location of a device from another device. Now, the problem I'm facing is that it crashes when i try to upload the latitude and longitude to firebase database. But, it doesn't crash if I use a Toast to just display the latitude and longitude.

DriverMapsActivity.java

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
String userid;
double lat;
double lon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_maps);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);




}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    List<String> providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
    if (null != locations && null != providerList && providerList.size() > 0) {
        double longitude = locations.getLongitude();
        double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {

                String state = listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                String subLocality = listAddresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lon = location.getLongitude();
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    assert mUser != null;
    userid = mUser.getUid();

    mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(userid).child("Latitude").setValue(lat);
    mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(userid).child("Longitude").setValue(lon);

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                this);
    }


}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}
public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem is in this part

```
lat = location.getLatitude();
    lon = location.getLongitude();
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    assert mUser != null;
    userid = mUser.getUid();

    mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(userid).child("Latitude").setValue(lat);
    mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(userid).child("Longitude").setValue(lon);
```

I've even tried to upload values using a java class and then passing the values to that class.`

Could someone please help?!

Logcat

```
E/UncaughtException(18714):     at com.oxford.gpstracker.DriverMapsActivity.onLocationChanged(DriverMapsActivity.java:169)
E/UncaughtException(18714):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdi.zzq(Unknown Source)
E/UncaughtException(18714):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdw.zzb(Unknown Source)
E/UncaughtException(18714):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdx.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
E/UncaughtException(18714):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/UncaughtException(18714):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
E/UncaughtException(18714):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469)
```

Comment: Post logcat here to better help

Comment: I've pasted the logcat but it isn't in proper format. I had to pull it from my phone. That's why

Comment: Add your build gradle dependencies too

Comment: I'm sure that build.Gradle is proper because in another activity, I'm adding data to firebase database. And that's working properly without any errors. The error has to be in this activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mDatabaseReference` must be initialized before use.  You can do it immediately before use, as shown below or in `onCreate()`.

```
lat = location.getLatitude();
lon = location.getLongitude();
mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
assert mUser != null;
userid = mUser.getUid();

mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // ADDED

mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(userid).child("Latitude").setValue(lat);
mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(userid).child("Longitude").setValue(lon);
```